# breadcrumb not working with taxonomy

Tags: breadcrumbs, theming

Im using the zen theme to create a subtheme. I cannot display the breadcrumb properly. My url is using taxonomy as its parents so something along the lines of http://example.com/link1/title-article. I want the breadcrumb to be `"Home > Link1 > title article`.

Unfortunately I only have `Home / title-article` as the breadcrumb.
How can I resolve this? I havent changed the `zen_breadcrumb` function in the zen template..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [Crumbs](https://www.drupal.org/project/crumbs) module will do what you are looking for. It allows you to set the pattern for crumb generation. In your case the pattern for an article would be something along the lines of

`[node:field_tags]`

Home is automatically generated so this will give you a crumb path of: `Home >> Taxonomy Term`

If you want to include the article title, then you would just add [node:title] to the crumb pattern.

`[node:field_tags]/[node:title]`

Which would produce: `Home >> Taxonomy Term >> Title`